# Not able to filter rows of jtable with textfield in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

```
DBOperations objDB;
ArrayList alstStock;
private TableRowSorter sorter;
public void viewDailyStock() {
    initComponents();
    setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    objDB = new DBOperations();
    alstStock = objDB.getStockList();
    generateTable();
    txtSearch.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
            new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }
        @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }
        @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }
            });
    setVisible(true);
}


void generateTable() {
    Object data[][] = new Object[alstStock.size()][10];
    String date = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < alstStock.size(); i++) {
        StockBean objBean = (StockBean) alstStock.get(i);
        data[i][0] = i + 1;
        data[i][1] = objBean.getBrand();
        data[i][2] = objBean.getProductCode();
        data[i][3] = objBean.getProductName();
        data[i][8] = objBean.getItemInBox();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM d,yyyy");
        date = df.format(objBean.getDate());
        data[i][4] = date;
        data[i][5] = objBean.getUser();
        data[i][6] = objBean.getLotNumber();
        data[i][7] = objBean.getQtyInItem();
        data[i][9] = objBean.getQtyInBox();
    }
    String header[] = {"S.No.", "Brand", "Code", "Name", "Date", "Added By", "Lot No.", "Qty In Item", "Item", "Qty In Boxes"};

    tblStock = new JTable(data,header);
    sorter=new TableRowSorter(tblStock.getModel());
    tblStock.setRowSorter(sorter);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblStock);
    setWidth();
    tblStock.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

}

private void newFilter() {
    RowFilter rf = null;
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(txtSearch.getText(), 3);
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception "+e);
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

DBOperations is a class for fetching data from database table. StockBean is a class of object with the getter and setter method.

This is my code of implementing row filter to the 4th column of jtable with a textfield but its not working.
Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by using this code :

```
   private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        

  String target = txtSearch.getText();  
  TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tblStock.getModel());
  tblStock.setRowSorter(sorter);
  sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*"+target+".*", yourColumnIndice));

  }
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are 0-based, so the 3rd column is index 2.

Also, your comment in `newFilter()` is incorrect.

```
private void newFilter() {
    RowFilter rf = null;
    //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(txtSearch.getText(), 3);
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception "+e);
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

You are calling `setRowFilter()` even if an exception is throw. Therefore if the table is currently being filtered and the new filter string causes an exception, the filter is reset to `null`. This means the current filter will be removed and the table's display **will** update.

Comment: sorry i have to do filtering for 4th column
even if i call setRowFilter() method in try block of private void newFilter() method, it doesnt work.

Comment: @user1630555: If that is not the issue, can you expand on what "its not working" means? Is it filtering anything? Are you getting an exception? Is `newFilter()` not being called by the event handler?

Comment: @user1630555: There isn't much else I can do without being able to run the code. You should run the code with the debugger and set a break point in each of your methods to make sure they are being called when you expect them to be.

Comment: i set the breakpoint on in try block of newFilter() method, this method is running but not filtering the table..